# How To Return an Array from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is a [JS demo](http://codepad.org/MEAsnKS6)

This is the [PHP code](http://codepad.org/mlHTm6kO)

I Don't Know why it was running and suddenly it don't need to run anymore, In addtion to that the result is not as i need i need to say as example:

```
alert(rs[0]); //and the alert result is 1
alert(rs[1]); //and the alert result is 2
```

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Any error in the console ? In the network tab ?

Comment: Why dont you use jQuery for ajax?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Check if your AJAX request fails. See if you get an error. Check the raw value of `request.responseText`. You know, basic debug stuff.

Comment: @AlexShilman, why should he?

Comment: looks completely fine, but `rs = new Array();` is unnessecary, simply just `var rs = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);`

Comment: why rs = new Array() is not necessary i need to put the result from php in a JS array ?

and i don't know any thing about debugging in Javascript/Ajax codes , any info. ?!

Comment: @davidkonrad: It's not a matter of should or not, it's just easier...

Comment: if success, `rs[2]=3` (according to the PHP-script) - and no need for declaring an array you are overwriting / redeclaring in the line after anyway. BTW, `rs = [];` is the best way to declare an array imho.

Comment: @AlexShilman, yes - the many, many thousand questions about `$.ajax` proofs that :) polemisch spoken :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
rs = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

instead of

```
rs = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
```

at line 19, the ajax object is xmlhttp in your case, ajaxRequest is undefined

Comment: fine nw if i need to return indexed array from php i.e. (key, value)

how can i make JS understand it 

for example i want to say (Var ob = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); )

then i wanna to alert ob.name ??

Comment: +1 for answer @Abdel-rahmanEl-Carpenter - `ob[0].name` will return the first name in your JSON "array".

Answer (score 0):

```
while (obj.length > 0) {

        var obj_new = obj.pop();

       document.getElementById("category_level_2").innerHTML += '<option  value="'+obj_new['ID']+'">'+obj_new['Name_category']+'</option>';   

        }
```

By using obj.pop() you can fetch an array.